# Unity(3.5) Interception in MVC 5

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container, interceptor, unity-interception

I am trying to use `Interception` in a `MVC` application.  The problem I am having is with the controllers.  Because the controllers are registered in the `Unity` container, and don't have interfaces, I am getting an error.  I think I need a way to exclude the controllers from the `Interception` process or can I do something else?  Is this possible or feasible? I asked a similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28195317/unity3-5-interception-not-working-in-mvc) on SO and, based on the comments I received, feel it's best to create another question.

Here's the error:

> Exception information: Exception type: ResolutionFailedException
>   Exception message: Resolution of the dependency failed, type =
>   "CSR.Presentation.Controllers.HomeController", name = "(none)".
>   Exception occurred while: Calling constructor
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.PolicyInjectionBehavior(Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.CurrentInterceptionRequest
>   interceptionRequest,
>   Microsoft.Practices.Unity.InterceptionExtension.InjectionPolicy[]
>   policies, Microsoft.Practices.Unity.IUnityContainer container).
>   Exception is: ArgumentException - Type passed must be an interface.

Here's the code;

```
// FIRST
   container.RegisterTypes(
       AllClasses.FromLoadedAssemblies(), 
       WithMappings.FromMatchingInterface, 
       WithName.Default,
       WithLifetime.ContainerControlled,
         t => new InjectionMember[] { 
            new Interceptor<InterfaceInterceptor>(),
            new InterceptionBehavior<PolicyInjectionBehavior>()});

// SECOND
   container.AddNewExtension<Interception>();

// THIRD    
   var first = new InjectionProperty("Order", 1);
   var second = new InjectionProperty("Order", 2);

   container.Configure<Interception>()
       .AddPolicy("logging")
       .AddMatchingRule<NamespaceMatchingRule>(
            new InjectionConstructor(
            new InjectionParameter("CSR.*")))             
       .AddCallHandler<LoggingCallHandler>(
            new ContainerControlledLifetimeManager(),
            new InjectionConstructor(),
            first);

// Controller ==> execution doesn't reach here using interception
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View("Index");
        }        
    }
```

Comment: did you find a solution for this? I am trying to set up interception to log calls to my controllers but no success yet. Thanks

Comment: @FabioMilheiro...Sorry, no I didn't

Comment: I just found this: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/469251/ASP-NET-MVC-controller-action-with-Interceptor-pat

but don't like it at all. It seems that using filters is the best way to apply interception to controllers.

Comment: @FabioMilheiro...Thanks and I tend to agree.  They are what's expected by other devs and this makes them more discoverable and maintainable.